# Normalize vector in MATLAB with first value 100

Tags: matlab, normalization

I have a vector:

```
0.02
-0.02
0
-0.02
-0.08
-0.05
-0.04
-0.1
0
0.05
0.05
0.05
0.08
0.04
```

How do I normalize this with the first value starting at 100?

Comment: what do you mean by the first value starting at 100? Do you mean you want your result to look something like 100, -100, 0, -100, -400?

Comment: What did you try and what was the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myArr = [0.02 -0.02 0 -0.02 -0.08 -0.05 -0.04 ... 
  -0.1 0 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.08 0.04]

myArr = 100*myArr/myArr(1)
```

Comment: How's this different from the [answer by @DavidKelley](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34746975/5211833) posted earlier?

Comment: @Adriaan judging by the time stamp, it is likely that they both started answering at the same time.

Comment: @GameOfThrows there's a full minute between the two, and I'd not even need 15 seconds to write this. Besides, he'd have seen the warning "another answer has been posted", clicked the answer and realised it was  the same.

Comment: @Adriaan You are a quicker typer than me. I started an answer, wrote this in Matlab (I always assert my answers prior to posting them, even simple ones), then posted this answer, and at that time, noticed another answer was posted just prior to mine. Also, to be picky, the other answer uses a redundant `.` division when dividing vector by scalar. Anyway, this happens, see [e.g. this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224733/what-if-two-different-users-post-nearly-identical-answers-to-a-question-at-the-s). In the end, people tend to upvote the first answer posted if alike.

Answer (score 5):

Simply divide by the first element and multiply by 100:

```
a = [0.02 -0.02 0 -0.02 -0.08 -0.05 -0.04 -0.1 0 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.08 0.04]
b = a ./ a(1) * 100
b =
    100  -100     0  -100  -400  -250  -200  -500     0   250   250   250   400   200
```